# Restriction to follow mm/dd/yyyy in jquery masking?

Tags: javascript, jquery, masking

i am using jquery masking in my project to allow the date in mm/dd/yyyy like below

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery.maskedinput-1.2.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        //Input Mask for date of birth or date in general
        $("#txtDOB").mask("99/99/9999");

    });
</script>
```

But at present user can enter any value greater than 12 and 0 for month. Similarly for days greater than 31 . Is there
a way i can restrict so that user can't type more than 12 or 0 for mm . similarly he can type more than 31 or 0 for days ?

i have java script validation in place at submit but is there a way to restrict while type ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with this:

```
$("#txtDOB").mask('d/m/y', {'translation': {
    d: {pattern: /[0-2]?\d|3[0-1]/}, 
    m: {pattern: /0[1-9]|1[0-2]/},  
    y: {pattern: /[1-2]\d{3}/}
  }
});
```

> ### **UPDATED**
>
> the mask has three parts, `d`for days, `m`for months and `y` for years (you can switch the order if you want), and I have made 3 regex, one for each.

- `d` pattern: there are two posible matches (two options) separated by `|`

  - first one `[0-2]?\d` first digit should be `0 up to 2`(`[0-2]`) and its optional (`?`) the second digit could be `0-9` (`\d`)
  - second one `3[0-1]` first digit is `3` and the second one only can be `0` or `1`
- `m` pattern: there are two options separated by `|`

  - first one `0[1-9]`, if month start by `0` the second digit could be `1 to 9`
  - second one `1[0-2]`, if month start by `1`the second digit only coudl be `0 to 2`
- `y`pattern `[1-2]\d{3}`: first digit can be `1` or `2` and then should be 3 digits `[0-9]`.

Comment: can you please explain this regex ?

Comment: Thanks a lot . will try it and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Could try something like this

```
    if ($(day).val() > 31 || $(month).val() > 12 || $(year).val() > 2014) {
            $(this).val('');
    }
```